query in a web page by requests python
I am trying to write a piece of code by requests in python to fill out a form in the following website (https://linelist.pa.uky.edu/newpage/) and print the information the submmited query shows:
import requests

url = "https://linelist.pa.uky.edu/newpage/"
params = {"wavelength_range": "6100-6500"}  # Specify the wavelength range
r = requests.post(url, data=params)
print(r.text)

but the problem is that it does not print me the results as they are shown in the website after submitting the query.

Your target app doesn't have the param name wavelength_range instead it has a wavl param with a bunch of other params, and you're requesting the wrong endpoint with a POST method instead of /newpage/cgi-bin/qlines.cgi
here is the sample code that fetching data from https://linelist.pa.uky.edu/newpage/cgi-bin/qlines.cgi using POST method not https://linelist.pa.uky.edu/newpage/
Sample Code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://linelist.pa.uky.edu/newpage/cgi-bin/qlines.cgi"
params = "wavl=6100-6500&wave=Angstrom&air=Vacuum&radv=&rvtp=vrad&wacc=&elmion=&akival=&akitype=Aki&akizero=incl&abun=&depl=&elo=&ener=cm%5E-1&ehi=&nmax=&type=All&auto=Show&form=spec&form=type&form=term&form=angm&jval=usej&tptype=as_a&form=ener&mode=HTML+&mlin=10000"  # Specify the wavelength range}
r = requests.post(url, data=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
for i in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    print(f"{i.text.strip()}: {i['href']}")

Sample output:
2D-4Po: qmult.cgi?10?3?15027?15045?SpTtTrAmLvMjPa?0
3Fo-3G: qmult.cgi?14?10?22429?22444?SpTtTrAmLvMjPa?0
3G-(5/2,3/2)o: qmult.cgi?31?3?58494?58533?SpTtTrAmLvMjPa?0
ASD: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASBib1/Elevbib/make_query.cgi?spectra=Ga%20IV&method=EL&order=1
(5/2,1/2)-1Fo: qmult.cgi?31?3?58582?58599?SpTtTrAmLvMjPa?0
ASD: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASBib1/Elevbib/make_query.cgi?spectra=Ga%20IV&method=EL&order=1
f6D-6Po: qmult.cgi?25?0?40739?41200?SpTtTrAmLvMjPa?0
ASD: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASBib1/Elevbib/make_query.cgi?spectra=Mn%20I&method=EL&order=1
f6D-6Po: qmult.cgi?25?0?40739?41201?SpTtTrAmLvMjPa?0
ASD: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASBib1/Elevbib/make_query.cgi?spectra=Mn%20I&method=EL&order=1
4Do-4D: qmult.cgi?9?0?12135?12187?SpTtTrAmLvMjPa?0

Let me know if this is ok for you!
